# All Badge IDs on every network

Tags: app, placeholder, badges

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: table of badge id's]

### About

This script gets all the Badge IDs of every network. For more information go to [this wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369665/is-there-a-table-of-badge-ids-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/).

#### License

This script is under the `MIT License` on Github and is completely free for anybody to use.

#### Download

This script is, together with the table in an array of formats, available on [Github](https://github.com/gurkensaas/StackExchange-Badge-IDs)

#### Platform

This script sadly only works on macOS with Google Chrome or Chromium-based browsers. The tables should work on all operating systems.

### Contact

You can contact me in the comments under this post, the [wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369665/is-there-a-table-of-badge-ids-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/).

### Code

The reason for the low compatibility is my use of [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript).
You can contribute using Github.